# If i have multiple for loops can i use i each time or do i have to use different variables?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {

// printf blah blah; 

   //i = 18;

}



// code



for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {

//printf blah;

//i = height;

}
```

or would I have to use j for the next loop and different variables for each loop

Comment: How about using 'i' never?  Give the index var a meaningful name.

Comment: @MartinJames: Such as `loopIndex`? `i`, `j` and so on are fine as indices for small loops.

Comment: @MartinJames it all really depends on the function, if you want to waste your writing index, every lamdba would be the worst thing in thw world

Comment: It's totally up to you.

Comment: Well you have re assigned i in you next loop so the i will be 0 and you can use i your next loop

Comment: @MOehm how should I know what the OP's program data items are?  Maybe loopIndex is the best that can be done, and so no point in avoiding 'i', but who knows?  Only OP.  Once devs start with 'i', it's one small step for a man, one giant leap for 'i,j,k,l,m,n,a,b,c,a1,a2,a3' gross unintelligibility, something that SO posters are very good at:(

Comment: Then, some idio.. idiosyncratic infidel will use 'i' in one loop and then re-use it an another, just to make debugging. maintenance and enhancement as difficult as possible:(

Comment: @MartinJames: You've got that wrong, I'm afraid. Not knowing the nature of the OP's items should have been a good reason _not_ to post a regulatory comment. Unfortunately, posting self-satisfied "universal truths" of doubtful quality is also something SO posters are very good at. As far as looping indices are concerned, I'd rather say that `i` is the most meaningful name for an index. It is more important to find a good name for data items and to use indices consistently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler supports C99 then it is much better to declare the control variable inside the loop statement provided that the variable is not used outside the loop.

For example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    //...
}
```

If the compiler does not support C99 then you can use the same variable `i` for loops. It is desirable that it would be used only as the control variable of loops.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the same variable in different loops (as long as it remains in scope).

The only thing you need to be careful is, in case, you miss the initialization, the last saved value will be used next time.

Comment: what do u mean by "remains in scope"?

Answer (score 3):

In the example you give, with two consecutive loops, yes.

But be careful, don't do that with nested loops.
Example of what you should not do:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
}
```

This won't write only 15 hellos, but an infinity.